# Hint for SML type inference

Tags: sml, type-inference

I am new to SML and I am trying to practice in SML type reference.I am trying to deduct the below types:

```
a)fun add42 x =x+42
b)fun comp F G = let fun C x = G(F(x)) in C end
c)fun compA42 x = comp add42 x
d)val foo = compA42 add42
e)fun compCompA42 x = comp compA42 x
```

I think the solutions for the first four is:

```
a)int->int
b)(a->b)->(b->c)->a->c
c)(int->a)->int->a
d)int->int
```

But I am  a little bit confused about the last one.
Is there any hint to deduct the last type??

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do this manually, step-by-step:

```
fun compCompA42 x = comp compA42 x
```

1. It's a function, so `compCompA42` has type `α -> β`.
2. `compCompA42`'s return value must be of the same type as `comp compA42 x`, i.e. `β = typeof(comp compA42 x)`.
3. We already now the most general type for `comp`:

   `(a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c`

Now, we need to specialize it for the case when `a -> b = typeof(compA42)` and `(b -> c) = α`:

4. `a -> b = typeof(compA42) = (int -> d) -> int -> d`. From this equation follows that `a = int -> d` and `b = int -> d`.
5. So, `α = b -> c = (int -> d) -> c` and `β = typeof(comp compA42 x) = a -> c = (int -> d) -> c`.
6. Finally, our most general type for `compCompA42` is

   `α -> β = ((int -> d) -> c) -> (int -> d) -> c`.

---

Observe that you can always make some SML interpreter (e.g., smlnj) show you types:

```
- fun compCompA42 x = comp compA42 x;
val compCompA42 = fn : ((int -> 'a) -> 'b) -> (int -> 'a) -> 'b
```

And it's the same type we've got manually (just rename `d` to `'a` and `c` to `'b`).